# SOQL - Querying for a list of users the current user is following

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql, salesforce-chatter

In my app I display a list of the current users. I request it like this:

### Attempt 1

```
List<User> Following = [SELECT Id, Name, SmallPhotoUrl 
  FROM User 
  WHERE Id IN (
      SELECT ParentId 
      FROM EntitySubscription 
      WHERE SubscriberId = :UserInfo.getUserId()) 
    AND Id != :UserInfo.getUserId() 
  LIMIT 96];
```

This does exactly what it's supposed to when logged in as an admin but I found out that non-admins get an error:

> Implementation restriction: EntitySubscription only allows security
>   evaluation for non-admin users when LIMIT is specified and at most
>   1000

OK, no big deal, I'll just slap a LIMIT on there like so:

### Attempt 2

```
List<User> Following = [SELECT Id, Name, SmallPhotoUrl 
  FROM User 
  WHERE Id IN (
      SELECT ParentId 
      FROM EntitySubscription 
      WHERE SubscriberId = :UserInfo.getUserId() 
      LIMIT 1000) 
    AND Id != :UserInfo.getUserId() 
  LIMIT 96];
```

Easy, right? WRONG. This gives the following:

> expecting a right parentheses, found 'LIMIT'

OK...

I then tried breaking it out like so:

### Attempt 3

```
List<EntitySubscription> sub = [SELECT ParentId 
  FROM EntitySubscription 
  WHERE SubscriberId = :UserInfo.getUserId() 
  LIMIT 1000];
List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
for(EntitySubscription s : sub){
    ids.add(s.ParentId);
}
List<User> Following = [SELECT Id, Name, SmallPhotoUrl 
  FROM User 
  WHERE Id IN (:ids) 
    AND Id != :UserInfo.getUserId() 
  LIMIT 96];
```

I crossed my fingers and...

```
Invalid bind expression type of LIST<Id> for column of type Id
```

Hmm, I'd seen examples where this seemed to be possible, such as on the [developerforce boards](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Invalid-bind-expression-type-of-SOBJECT/td-p/110378), so I'm at a bit of a loss now.

So here we are. I need to select a list of user names and pictures that a particular user is following on Chatter. If there is a completely different way to go about it I'm open to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try removing the parenthesis around the bind, i.e. change:

```
WHERE Id IN (:ids)
```

to:

```
WHERE Id IN :ids
```

And also simplify the query by just making sure that your list of IDs doesn't contain the current user's ID:

```
List<EntitySubscription> sub = [SELECT ParentId 
  FROM EntitySubscription 
  WHERE SubscriberId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND ParentId != :UserInfo.getUserId()
  LIMIT 1000];

Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();

for(EntitySubscription s : sub){
    ids.add(s.ParentId);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Man, as soon as I your answer I knew it would work - and it does. I'll accept this as soon as I can (need to wait a few minutes still). Thanks!

Comment: This looks like it ought to be the answer.  If so, please mark it as the answer.